# C++ how to sort an array variable

Tags: c++

I got a parent class call

```
Shape
```

Shape got 2 child call

```
Square and Rectangle
```

Shape class got a variable call area, which is of int type

So i created some object of Square, Rectangle like this

```
int main()
{
    Shape *shaped[100];

    //then i did some adding of object..
    int areaValue;
    areaValue=1;

    shaped[0] = new Rectangle();
    shaped[0]->setArea(areaValue);

    areaValue=7;
    shaped[1] = new Square();
    shaped[1]->setArea(areaValue);

    areaValue=5;
    shaped[2] = new Square();
    shaped[2]->setArea(areaValue);

    shapeCounter = 3;

    sort(shaped[0],shaped[2]);

    for (int i=0;i<shapeCounter;i++)
    {
        cout << shaped[i].getArea() << endl;
    }

}
```

I try to sort by ascending area but it doesnt work. no position change, the area still in the  same sequence.

Thanks for all help!

Update:

I did the following changes at Shape.cpp

```
 bool Shape::orderByArea(const Shape* lhs, const shape* rhs)
    {
      return lhs->area() < rhs->area();
    }
```

Then at main.cpp I did this

```
std::sort(shaped, shaped + 3, orderByArea);
```

however i get an error, orderByArea was not declared in this scope.

**Another thing i tried was:**
To sort using vector

At Shape.h

```
public:

bool operator<const Shape& x) const
{
return area < x.area;
}
```

At main.cpp

```
vector<ShapeTwoD*> sortVector;
sortVector.clear();
sortVector.assign(shaped,shaped + shapeCounter);

sort(sortVector.begin(),sortVector.end());

for(int i=0;i<shapeCounter;i++)
{
cout << sortVector[i].toDisplay() << endl;
}
```

But nothing seems sorted. I try do a printout its position is same.

**Updates: Its fixed now. sort is working . Thanks to the experts !**

I got another question is

Shape *shaped[100];

How do i copy the value of

```
Shape *shaped[100];
```

into

```
vector<Shape> myVector;
```

instead of

```
vector<Shape*> myVector;
```

so i can use the normal object sort.

Comment: You need to define a function to tell std::sort how to sort your shapes. Also show us your class definitions of Rectangle and Square.

Comment: @WhozCraig , i used your Internal operator< recommendation, but nothing seems sorted .  I will update my question to let you know what i have done.

Comment: `operator<` is the wrong thing to do, because you have an array of *pointers*, not an array of objects. Honestly a book would be easier and you would learn more.

Comment: None of the answers have told you to write `bool Shape::orderByArea(...)`. That doesn't work.

Comment: @John, i know a book would be easier for me to learn more, but in my case of an array of objects, what should i do

Comment: None of your code above uses an array or vector of objects, *it's all pointers*. You  have been told several methods to sort with *pointers*, they all work, read them and write the code correctly.

Comment: `Shape *shaped[100];` this is an array of pointers. `vector<ShapeTwoD*> sortVector;` this is a vector of pointers. The `*` means *pointer*. If you have some other code which really is an array or vector of objects, then you need to show it to us before anyone can tell you how to sort it.

Comment: @John, thanks i manage to work it out with the second function. I got a question is , for such kind of sort pointer. is there a way i can sort using boolean operator overload > or i really have to use function like sort_by_area below, i manage to do it with using function sort_by_area below

Comment: No you can't use operator<. That would be one way to sort objects, but it doesn't work with pointers.

Comment: You really need to understand the difference between objects and pointers to objects.

Comment: okay thanks john. I got another question is that Shape *shaped[100]; got about 3 shape , how do i get the content of *shaped copy into a vector object instead of a vector pointer like mine.

Comment: @juanchopanza Pointers are hard, but I agree, to get past the basics in C++ you need to understand them. Other languages make it easier of course.

Comment: updated 1 more question at my question. Will be good if can get some information :)

Comment: @user1595932 That sounds like a really bad thing to do. You are learning polymorphism, so you must have heard of *object slicing* and how it's a bad thing? The only way to do what you say is to write a loop and copy them one by one. But you will be doing object slicing that way, and I think you'll find that your program doesn't work as you expect it to. In other words I have to ask, why do you want to do that? It's almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @user1595932 OK, seen the update to your question. Just write a loop that copies the shapes one by one. Still think it's not a sensible thing to do.

Comment: @John, so the suggested is to keep things the way it is, means pointer to pointer, and it is form of polymorphism, yes i am learning polymorphism and its my key objective.

Comment: @user1595932 Yes, you need pointers for polymorphism, you'll will lose it if you start using objects.

Comment: @John, is polymorphism for c++ coding when i use things like parent and child.

Comment: Yes, it's for when you have classes which are related, like a Rectangle is a Shape and a Circle is a Shape. You use polymorphism (i.e. virtual functions) to specify what is the different between, say, Circles and Rectangles. So you should have a virtual getArea methods for Circle and Rectangle because the way you calculate the area of a Rectangle is different from the way you calculate the area of a Circle. But sometimes in your code you don't know whether you've got Rectangles or Circles, all you've got is Shapes, polymorphism helps with this.

Comment: It seems to me from the question above that you have one getArea method on Shape, not a different virtual getArea methods on Rectangle and Square. If that's what you have then you are doing it wrong and not using polymorphism.

Comment: because area is store in Parent, i got computeArea which is virtual for all child, they compute then store the value in parent shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code how did you expect the compiler to know that you wanted to sort by area, magic? I would recommend reading a book on the standard C++ library (aka the STL), it will explain how to do custom sorting. In your code you have an array of *pointers*, so you should write a *functor* that can order your pointers. Also your parameters to std::sort are wrong. Your array starts at `shaped`, and ends at `shaped + 3` (since you have three elements in your array).

```
struct sort_by_area
{
    static bool operator()(Shape* x, Shape* y)
    {
        return x->getArea() < y->getArea();
    }
};

sort(shaped, shaped + 3, sort_by_area());
```

Untested code, apologies for any mistakes.

Or you can use a function pointer as juanchopanza says.

Comment: Well, regarding your first sentence: C++ like this is magic :P (+1, good explanation.)

Comment: Hi there, got a bit of issue is that it say its not declared in scope, what should i do, cause i declare the method at Shape Class

Comment: You should put `struct sort_by_area ...` at the top of your code before main. If that's not the problem then post the entire error message and the line it is referring to.

Comment: @user1595932 based on your last edit, make it a non-member function.

Comment: Thanks its work now. selected as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had an array `shapes` full of `Shape*`, and that `Shape` has a method `int getArea() const;`, you need to define a less-than comparison logic, and then tell `std::sort` to use it. You can do the former by defining this kind of less-than function:

```
inline bool orderByArea(const Shape* lhs, const shape* rhs)
{
  return lhs->getArea() < rhs->getArea();
}
```

Then invoke `std::sort`, passing a pointer to the function:

```
#include <algorithm>

Shape* shapes[3] = ....; // array of three pointers to Shape
std::sort(shapes, shapes + 3, orderByArea);
```