# C++ Sorting a Array of Pointer to Objects

Tags: c++, class, sorting, shapes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ how to sort an array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207744/c-how-to-sort-an-array-variable)

I got a parent class call

```
Shape
```

Shape got 2 child call

```
Square and Rectangle
```

Shape class got a variable call area, which is of int type

So i created some object of Square, Rectangle like this

```
int main()
{
    Shape *shaped[100];

    //then i did some adding of object..
    int areaValue;
    areaValue=1;

    shaped[0] = new Rectangle();
    shaped[0]->setArea(areaValue);

    areaValue=7;
    shaped[1] = new Square();
    shaped[1]->setArea(areaValue);

    areaValue=5;
    shaped[2] = new Square();
    shaped[2]->setArea(areaValue);

    shapeCounter = 3;


     sort(shaped, shaped + 3, sort_by_area());


    for (int i=0;i<shapeCounter;i++)
    {
        cout << shaped[i].getArea() << endl;
    }

}
```

Then at e.g Square.cpp

I did this

```
struct sort_by_area
{
    static bool operator()(Shape* x, Shape* y)
    {
        return x->getArea() < y->getArea();
    }
};
```

This code above works. and can sort by area, but my question is that can i still sort if i don't use struct , cause if i don't use struct, it will say the sort_by_area is not declared in scope.

Must i really use struct so my main.cpp can access the sort code that is located at the child class .cpp

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "can i still sort if i don't use struct"? do you mean the Shape struct?

Comment: @Michael - I think OP means the `sort_by_area` object. user1595932 - what's wrong with using a comparison object? The `sort` function expects a function object and this is an easy way to provide one.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: Yes ok , i haven't noticed that he defined the comperator as a struct, it should be a regular comperator function.

Comment: @user1595932: Here is an example of what is the correct way to use sort http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/, http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/47440/

Comment: @Michael, but how do i redo my code so i can use the normal way of sorting , however i now is sorting an array of pointers to object . Without calling it as struct sort_by_area , and maybe some other forms or is it pratically ok to use struct

Comment: @user1595932 You have to use either a struct or a function pointer (Michael's answer). Those are the only two possibilities for an array of pointers.

Comment: This was [already answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207744/c-how-to-sort-an-array-variable). My answer explained clearly how to sort without a struct. What is the problem now?

Answer (score 5):

This works perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Shape{

private:
    int x;
public:
    void setArea(int x){
        this->x =  x;
    }
    int getArea(){
        return this->x;
    }
};

class Rectangle: public Shape{
public:
};

class Square: public Shape{
public:
};

bool sort_by_area (Shape* x,Shape* y) { return (x->getArea() < y->getArea()); }
int main()
{
    Shape *shaped[100];

    //then i did some adding of object..
    int areaValue,shapeCounter = 0;
    areaValue=1;

    shaped[0] = new Rectangle();
    shaped[0]->setArea(areaValue);

    areaValue=7;
    shaped[1] = new Square();
    shaped[1]->setArea(areaValue);

    areaValue=5;
    shaped[2] = new Square();
    shaped[2]->setArea(areaValue);

    shapeCounter = 3;


    sort(shaped, shaped + 3, sort_by_area);


    for (int i=0;i<shapeCounter;i++)
    {
        cout << shaped[i]->getArea() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1595932: if this answer answered your needs , accept it